# node-gyp seems to fail when building

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, inotify

I'm trying to run yarn install and i get this error when it gets to `inotify`. i also get the same errors of i directly run yarn add `inotify`. node-gyp seems to fail when building. not sure what else to interpret from the logs.

Strangely, this package can be successfully deployed and built on `heroku`, i just can't get the dev environment to work on my machine. This makes me think it must be some kind of versioning issue? My best understanding of the logs would also be that one of these packages is using one syntax while another uses something different.

Finally, this code has worked on a mac previously - not sure if that affects any well-known packages.

Any hints much appreciated!

I'm using:

> node version v14.15.5
>
> yarn version 1.22.15

These are the install logs. Package.json is below

```
username@username-X556UAK:~/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir$ yarn install
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b461732-5a1e-43a8-b133-4d39c79671d9 > api > puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker > @cliqz/adblocker-puppeteer@1.18.7" has incorrect peer dependency "puppeteer@5.x".
error /home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify: Command failed.                                                                             
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@14.15.5 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.18 found at "/usr/bin/python2"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/inotify/src/bindings.o
In file included from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
../src/bindings.h:10:27: error: ‘Handle’ has not been declared
   10 |    static void Initialize(Handle<Object> target);
      |                           ^~~~~~
../src/bindings.h:10:33: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
   10 |    static void Initialize(Handle<Object> target);
      |                                 ^
../src/bindings.cc:11:27: error: variable or field ‘Initialize’ declared void
   11 |  void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
      |                           ^~~~~~
../src/bindings.cc:11:27: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
../src/bindings.cc:11:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   11 |  void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
      |                                        ^
../src/bindings.cc:11:42: error: ‘exports’ was not declared in this scope
   11 |  void Inotify::Initialize(Handle<Object> exports) {
      |                                          ^~~~~~~
../src/bindings.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE NodeInotify::Inotify::AddWatch(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/bindings.cc:146:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToObject()’
  146 |   Local<Object> args_ = info[0]->ToObject();
      |                                           ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2822:44: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2822 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2822:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/bindings.cc:149:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  149 |   if (!args_->Has(path_sym)) {
      |                           ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3752:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3752 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3752:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3758:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3758 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index);
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3758:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:154:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  154 |   if (!args_->Has(callback_sym) ||
      |                               ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3752:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3752 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3752:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3758:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3758 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index);
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3758:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:155:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  155 |    !args_->Get(callback_sym)->IsFunction()) {
      |                            ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3717 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3720 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:160:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  160 |   if (!args_->Has(watch_for_sym)) {
      |                                ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3752:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3752 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3752:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3758:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Has(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3758 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Has(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index);
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3758:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:163:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  163 |    if (!args_->Get(watch_for_sym)->IsInt32()) {
      |                                 ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3717 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3720 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:166:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  166 |    mask |= args_->Get(watch_for_sym)->Int32Value();
      |                                    ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3717 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3720 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:172:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  172 |   String::Utf8Value path(args_->Get(path_sym));
      |                                             ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3717 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3720 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:182:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
  182 |   inotify->handle()->Set(descriptor, args_->Get(callback_sym));
      |                                                             ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3717 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3720 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE NodeInotify::Inotify::RemoveWatch(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/bindings.cc:195:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
  195 |   watch = info[0]->Int32Value();
      |                               ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2869:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2869 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2869:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/bindings.cc: In static member function ‘static void NodeInotify::Inotify::Callback(uv_poll_t*, int, int)’:
../src/bindings.cc:262:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
  262 |     obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("watch").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(event->wd));
      |                                                                                      ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3670 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3673 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
../src/bindings.cc:263:87: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
  263 |     obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("mask").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(event->mask));
      |                                                                                       ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3670 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3673 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
../src/bindings.cc:264:91: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
  264 |     obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("cookie").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(event->cookie));
      |                                                                                           ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3670 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3673 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
../src/bindings.cc:267:104: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::String>)’
  267 |      obj->Set(Nan::New<String>("name").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<String>(event->name).ToLocalChecked());
      |                                                                                                        ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3670 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3673 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
      |                                     ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
../src/bindings.cc:275:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Get(Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)’
  275 |     Local<Value> value = handle->Get(Nan::New<Integer>(event->wd));
      |                                                                  ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
 3717 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>, uint32_t)’
 3720 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
      |                                           ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/bindings.cc:279:34: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  279 |     callback.Call(handle, 1, argv);
      |                                  ^
In file included from ../src/node_inotify.h:14,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
../../nan/nan.h:1722:3: note: declared here
 1722 |   Call(v8::Local<v8::Object> target
      |   ^~~~
../src/bindings.cc:285:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToString()’
  285 |      handle->Delete(wd->ToString());
      |                                  ^
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../src/node_inotify.h:5,
                 from ../src/bindings.h:4,
                 from ../src/bindings.cc:2:
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2810:44: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2810 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~
/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2810:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make: *** [inotify.target.mk:112: Release/obj.target/inotify/src/bindings.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-74-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/node" "/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/myusername/Documents/myprojectdir/myprojectdir/node_modules/inotify
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "api",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon --watch '**/*' -e ts,tsx,js  --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec 'ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json' src/server.ts",
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
    "start:redis": "docker-compose up -d",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production tsc"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node":"14.15.5",
    "npm": "6.14.11",
    "yarn": "1.22.15"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/server.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^5.4.4",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.27.44",
    "@types/redis": "^2.8.31",
    "@types/user-agents": "^1.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "prettier": "~2.2.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-router": "^0.1.15",
    "express-query-boolean": "^2.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "puppeteer": "^10.2.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.1.18",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.11.11",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.7.8",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
    "redis": "^3.1.2",
    "user-agents": "^1.0.738",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is build essentials required for this? Almost forget.

Comment: It seems that some version of peer dependency is breaking on Linux and worked fine on other environments. Need to get more details to debug it at least for me.

Comment: running "node-gyp rebuild" directly leads to "cannot find module 'nopt'" 

but then "yarn add nopt" takes me back to the same install and error message as my original post.

is this any help?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am getting this error when trying to install packages for a node project.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm having the same issue as well... Did you fix it? If yes, do you know how?

Comment: @Latrova I had to use Node 14 for my project and adjust some dependencies.